# Holonomic splitting

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, h-principle

I am reading the book "Introduction to the h-Principle" by Eliashberg and Mishachev. At the moment I try to understand the Section 1.7 Holonomic splitting on page 12 but without success. I do not understand the Holonomic splitting proposition. What does it exactly say? Can one put this in mathematical language? I think it means that over some sufficiently small ball $U\subset V$ one can write the bundle $X^{(r)}\rightarrow V$ as the trivial fibration $U\times \mathbb{R}^{qN_{r}} \rightarrow U$. What I do not understand is why one needs a holonomic section for that?  Hope there is somebody who can explain those things to me.

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Why off-topic?

Comment: It would be easier for others to answer if you provided the full text of the section you're asking about.  That's no reason to close the question though; I've voted to reopen.

Comment: What's wrong with the bit of the proposition starting "In other words..."? That seems like a comprehensible description of the proposition. In particular it's more complicated than just the existence of a trivialization (which I agree has nothing to do with holonomy); it's demanding a trivialization by holonomic sections. (PS: As far as I can tell the person who first voted to close your question has never answered a topology or differential geometry question, so I wouldn't worry too much about it being a meaningful vote.)